# Cloning git private repo using Integrity Continuous Integration causing problem

Tags: heroku, integrity

I have successfully deployed Integrity on Heroku. I have been able to build script for public repo on git and the build runs successfully.
But running integrity for private repo gives me error as

```
error: The requested URL returned error: 401\nerror: The requested URL returned error: 401\nerror: The requested URL returned error: 401\n"
"error: pathspec 'origin/master' did not match any file(s) known to git.\n"
```

I am using the https version for cloning since heroku does not ssh cloning.

I think that for cloning private repo we need to provide password, so is there any way in Integrity to provide a password?

Or is there any other way for the same.

Comment: May I ask you how did you configure Integrity to fetch from private repo?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to uncheck the "Public project" checkbox in Integrity project setting.
Secondly, you need to pass the password on the https url. 
And that should work as it works for me :)